# SQL: Select key based on missing value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table created like this
Table:

```
key      value
1        10000
1        10001        
2        10001
```

And I want to select key 2 because it has 10001 but not 10000. Is there a simple way? I tried using joins but I have no idea how to make join select only missing value.

Comment: isn't that duplicate key?

Comment: Your question is not clear, as you are saying you want to select key 2 because it has 10001 but key 1 also has 10001.

Comment: The question is clear enough :-p

Comment: Please clarify your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for `key`s that don't have all of the available `value`s, you can do that by comparing the number of `DISTINCT value`s for each key to the number of `DISTINCT value`s in the entire table.

```
SELECT `key` FROM `table` 
GROUP BY `key`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) < (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT value) FROM `table`)
```

Seen in action at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9bb0/3)

If there are only a particular set of values you're interested in, you can change this to using hardcoded values.

```
SELECT `key` FROM `table`
WHERE value IN (10001, 10000) 
GROUP BY `key`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) < 2
```

For this to generalize to a larger number of values, the number in the `HAVING` clause needs to match the number of elements in the `IN` condition.

Comment: Thanks, second example is exactly what I needed. Mahmoud Gamal's example also does it. Thanks to him also.

Comment: If you just want "all keys that don't have a 10000", Mahmoud's answer is correct. If you have a key that doesn't have an 10001 either, it won't show up in my second query.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.`key`
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.`key` NOT IN(SELECT `key` 
                      FROM tablename 
                      WHERE value = 10000);
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3350/15)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to approach this problem is to put the logic in the `having` clause.  The following counts the number of times each key appears and applies your logic:

```
select "key"
from t
group by "key"
having sum(value = 10000) = 0 and
       sum(value = 10001) > 0;
```

This is using a MySQL feature where boolean expressions (`value = 10000`) are treated as integers, with `0` being false and `1` being true.  So, sum(`value = 10000`) counts the number of rows where value is `10000` for each `key`.