# Get values that only appear once in a column

Tags: sql

I have 2 columns: Name of company, Field of expertise

In these 2 columns, we can find several compagnies that are experts in different field.

Let's say I want to find ONLY the companies that are expert in "tech" and NOTHING else.

Example of list:

```
Company ABC, Tech
Company ABC, Music
Company XYZ, Tech
```

The result should be `"Company XYZ"`.

How can I do that?

I tried:

`Where Field of expertise is like "tech"`

But the result in that case will be: `Company ABC, Company XYZ`.

That's not what I want and I can't figure out how

Comment: Here is a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595326/sql-select-key-based-on-missing-value

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate by company end count distinct fields of expertise, or you can use an anti-join.

The first option would look like:

```
select name
from (
  select name,
    count(case when field = 'Tech' then 'x' end) as ct,
    count(case when field <> 'Tech' then 'x' end) as cn
  from t
  group by name
) x
where ct > 0 and cn = 0
```